# Excel Sheet Insert/Update Performance Comparison in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Currently I am working on Excel sheet module of XXX project.
I need to optimize performance of Excel record insert and update because they have millions of record with very complex condition and many cell applying different formula.

> *So my problem is that which one is faster insert record with create new excel sheet or in edit mode insert record on already created xyz excel template.*

Right now I am using **NPOI** **plugin** for creating excel file.

Comment: I've never used the NPOI plugin for editing spreadsheets but have used the open xml sdk for the same purpose and found it to be very useful.  Have you looked at the open xml sdk or is that not an option?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot test both to see [which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Actually current scenario I am using only create new excel sheet with many record so it taking around 40 to 50 min.